# Determining if Poset based on Domain and Comparison Operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

Can someone help me with how to think about the below problem? I know that a poset is a relation which is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive, but unless I'm dealing with finite sets I have a lot of difficulty thinking through whether the properties fit.

---

Which of the following are posets?

- (a). $(R,=)$
- (b). $(R,|)$
- (c). $(Z^+,|)$
- (d). $(Z,\le)$

Looking at the Reals in (a), an arbitrary number 1.738 is always going to equal 1.738 in comparison, so it equals and relates to itself so is Reflexive. However, it isn't Antisymmetric?

Comment: Equality on $\Bbb R$ *is* antisymmetric. Antisymmetry of a relation $S$ says that if $x\mathrel{S}y$ and $y\mathrel{S}x$, then $x=y$. Now replace $S$ by $=$; is it true that if $x=y$ and $y=x$, then $x=y$? Most definitely! Therefore $=$ is an antisymmetric relation on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you see how (b) and (c) are different? (d) ought to be easy.